# How to translate a menu item in Main Menu with a path to a page View

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I'm sure I've done before, but I'm working in a fresh drupal installation and I guess I missed some configuration related to translation.

> ```
> 1) I created a new View which generate a Page.
> 2) I set No menu for Menu  (see image 1)
> 3) I set /inmuebles for Path  (see image 1)
> 4) In the Main Menu I added 2 links one for each language (english and spanish)  (see image 2)
> 5) Each link are set to the correct language (see image 3) 
> 6)The problem: both link are shown in both languages. (see image 4)
> ```

Of course I need the links to be shown **ONLY** in their respective languages.

**Image 1**

[image: image 1]

**Image 2**

[image: image 2]

**Image 3**

[image: image 3]

**Image 4**

[image: image 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a problem related to Superfish module which I'm using to generate the main menu. Here is the patch for the superfish module [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1410078#comment-5575240)